# Multi-part upload S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to complete a multi-part upload to S3 where I was able to generate key and upload id from below command. When I pass the values to complete the upload, I'm getting the error. I googled to figureout this error pops up when we use int value in string datatypes. Can someone help pls why this occurs in S3 upload.

```
bash-3.2$ aws s3api create-multipart-upload --bucket awspythnautomation --key 'docker'
{
    "Bucket": "awspythnautomation",
    "Key": "docker",
    "UploadId": "ySvpOo_9DwDLmfB84GqvJQAQeZQi1_U6_Qs2StKpvxCI.tKTFJKES9nNXDoY5zqkJX4yEuPdcICwTZ.X5xwkaNyYop1r9VOloMKjxji_TakQYLobYy7IcRoUUuHcebgh"
} 

bash-3.2$ aws s3api complete-multipart-upload --multipart-upload fileb://Docker.dmg --bucket awspythnautomation --key 'docker' --upload-id ySvpOo_9DwDLmfB84GqvJQAQeZQi1_U6_Qs2StKpvxCI.tKTFJKES9nNXDoY5zqkJX4yEuPdcICwTZ.X5xwkaNyYop1r9VOloMKjxji_TakQYLobYy7IcRoUUuHcebgh

***'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int***
```

Comment: what is this fileb://Docker.dmg. seems some mistype here

Comment: @MadhavKumarJha I tried with different formats, pdf and got the below error. 
***Error parsing parameter '--multipart-upload': Unable to load paramfile (s3-dg.pdf), text contents could not be decoded.  If this is a binary file, please use the fileb:// prefix instead of the file:// prefix.***

So when I add fileb its throwing the above error. 
***'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int***